# What is the maths name for a set which contains the Domain and Codomain of a function?

Tags: terminology, sets, functional-programming, category-theory

Im interested in this so that I can name a type parameter in a program I'm writing.

There is function that that has three parameters.

D, Domain

C, Codomain

X, where D is a subset of X and C is a subset of X

What is the special name for X, if there is one at all?

This is interesting from a program security prespective as by setting X we can constrain information to only flow within X.

Maybe I should be using category theory names here instead? If so what would these names be?

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, you could try math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: There is no such name as far as I know. If you have an interesting idea, you should develop and explore it even if you don't know a good name for the concepts involved. Let your ideas meet reality and see what happens.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/120153/755, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3528869/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it was cross-posted.

Comment: I felt this question was especially related related to both computer science and maths, also in general are the two subjects not moving closer together?